# how to union 3 table and group same id amount?

Tags: sql

how to solve 3 table and group same id?

```
   t1
----------
Id   a
1   100
1   600
2   800

  t2
----------
Id    b
1    600
2    700
3    400


  t3
----------
Id    c
2    400
3    800
4    100
```

i want  result like this:

```
Id     a        b      c 
------------------------------
 1    700      600   
 2    800      700    400      
 3             400    800
 4                    100
```

Same id group by

Comment: That's not a union, that's known as a join.  A union combines 2 different queries.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: dbms sql...............

Comment: what is dbms sql???? Do you know know which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do the fact you have id in several table youn should get, eg: using union ,all the id you need  for join

```
  select t.id, t1.a, t2.b, t3.c
  from ( 
       select id 
       from t1
       union
       select id
       from t2 
       union 
       select id 
       from t3 ) AS t 
    left join t1 on t.id = t1.id
    left join t2 on t.Id = t2.Id
    left join t3 on t.Id = t3.Id
```

and if you need sum  for a,b,c

```
   select t.id, sum(t1.a), sum(t2.b), sum(t3.c)
      from ( 
           select id 
           from t1
           union
           select id
           from t2 
           union 
           select id 
           from t3 ) AS t 
        left join t1 on t.id = t1.id
        left join t2 on t.Id = t2.Id
        left join t3 on t.Id = t3.Id
    group by t.id
```

Comment: That would not return the row with `id = 4` from table `t3`

Comment: i use ms access data base and 3 table use t1,t2,t3 like this i want get a querry in ms access self  id group and sum - a colomn, sum -b colomn, sum -c colomn like this pls help solvethis

Comment: You are using SQL or MS-ACCESS .. anyway answer  updated  adding as for tablename alias

Answer (score 0):

To ensure that you are taking all possible values use full outer join. Though this will not work in mySQL. If that is the case then look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796872/full-outer-join-in-mysql)

```
select coalesce(t1.id,t2.id,t3.id) as id, sum(t1.a) as a, sum(t2.b) as b,sum(t3.c) as c
from t1
outer join t2
   on t1.id = t2.id
outer join t3
   on t1.id = t3.id
      or t2.id = t3.id
group by id
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be misunderstanding you, but looks like you just need to join the table more than doing a Union Operation on them. Below statement will only return records where all three tables have at least one record with the same id.

SQL would be:

```
SELECT TBL1.ID,
   TBL1.A,
   TBL2.B,
   TBL3.C
FROM A TBL1 (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN B TBL2 (NOLOCK) ON TBL1.ID = TBL2.ID
INNER JOIN C TBL3 (NOLOCK) ON TBL1.ID = TBL3.ID
```

Two questions:
1. Which SQL engine to you use?
2. and do you need to return values where one table does not have the id?

Comment: The `nolock` makes no sense (and you need a full outer join anyway)

Comment: use ms access data base and 3 table use t1,t2,t3 like this i want get a querry in ms access self id group and sum - a colomn, sum -b colomn, sum -c colomn like this pls help solvethis